# jquery to run in iframe when created on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to first create an `iframe` and then inject into it jQuery library and then have an alert to say that jQuery has loaded.

The jQuery library is being inserted into the `iframe` head as expected and the alert on jQuery load into the body.

The problem is, it does not show the alert and instead says `jQuery is not defined`.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Here is the code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>iFrame Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var insertScript = function(src){
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.async = false;
                script.src = src;
                $('iframe').contents().find('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            }

            var insertScriptContent = function(code){
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.async = false;
                script.innerHTML  = code;
                $('iframe').contents().find('body')[0].appendChild(script);
            }

            $(function(){
                $('iframe').load(function(){
                    var contents = $('iframe').contents();
                    insertScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');
                    insertScriptContent('jQuery(function(){ alert("loaded"); });');
                });
            });
        </script>

        <div class="output">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a straight answer, but should help you figure out what you need: [Accessing iframe content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe). Keep in mind, this will not work if the iframe is loaded with content from another domain.

Comment: i meant to say its same domain and actually same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading jQuery asynchronously (despite the `script.async=false`) and then loading your alert script immediately after that. jQuery is not yet loaded when that script runs, so you get the undefined `jQuery` reference.

As a quick fix, I added a `setInterval()` that waits until `jQuery` is defined. I also made these other changes:

- Removed the `script.async = false;` both places because it doesn't do any good.
- Removed the `$('iframe').load()` wrapper. When I tested your code, the callback function in that wrapper never gets called at all. That's not surprising since nothing is being loaded into the iframe at that point.
- Changed the two places where you use `document.createElement()` to use the iframe document (called `iframedoc` in my version) instead. It works OK using `document`, but I'm a bit more comfortable creating those scripts under the document they will be loaded into.
- Changed two instances of `...find(something)[0].appendChild();` to the simpler `...find(something).append();`.

Here's the working code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

    <title>iFrame Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var $contents = $('iframe').contents();
            var iframedoc = $contents[0];

            var insertScript = function(src) {
                var script = iframedoc.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = src;
                $('iframe').contents().find('head').append(script);
            }

            var insertScriptContent = function(code) {
                var script = iframedoc.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.innerHTML = code;
                $('iframe').contents().find('body').append(script);
            }

            insertScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js');

            insertScriptContent(
                'var timer = setInterval( function() {' +
                    'if( typeof jQuery == "undefined" ) return;' +
                    'clearInterval( timer );' +
                    'jQuery(function(){ alert("loaded"); });' +
                '}, 50 )'
            );

        });
    </script>

    <div class="output">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That was good for a first pass, but there's a simpler way to do it. I tried replacing the two script functions with jQuery code, so here is another working version:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

    <title>iFrame Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var $contents = $('iframe').contents();

            $contents.find('head').append(
                '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script>'
            );

            $contents.find('body').append(
                '<script>' +
                    'jQuery(function(){ alert("loaded"); });' +
                '<\/script>'
            );

        });
    </script>

    <div class="output">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Oddly enough, this one works OK *without* the `setInterval()` timer, so I took that code out. I'm not sure exactly why this works - which is not a comforting feeling - but it does seem to be consistent in the browsers I tested it in.

And finally, here is a non-working experiment. In the past I've used `document.write()` targeting an iframe to good effect. So I thought I would try that:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

    <title>iFrame Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var $contents = $('iframe').contents();
            var iframedoc = $contents[0];

            iframedoc.write(
                '<!doctype html>',
                '<html>',
                '<head>',
                    '<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"><\/script>',
                '</head>',
                '<body>',
                    '<script>',
                        'debugger;',
                        'jQuery( function(){ alert("loaded"); } );',
                    '<\/script>',
                '</body>',
                '</html>'
            );
        });
    </script>

    <div class="output">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This version does load jQuery and the inline script into the iframe, and it executes the `jQuery()` call in the inline script. But it never calls the callback function with the `alert()` in it. This actually relates to something I'm working on, so I'll probably take another look at it tomorrow, but in the meantime I left the experimental code in case you're curious. I changed it to use the uncompressed jQuery inside the iframe for easy debugging, and left a `debugger;` statement in there.

Comment: the annoying thing is that it doesnt work on my iphone... because the iframe has no src it never completes the load!